# How to configure the value of ccsid for MQ Explorer to be used?

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

The other day i tried to add new remote MQGR through MQ explorer but it failed with below error:

```
AMQ4052 Coded character set ID error. Cannot convert a command message to the CCSID of the target queue manager.
```

The ccsid used by remote QMGR is 5488, and the ccsid of local pc where the MQ explorer installed is 1381, i suppose.

My question is:

> 1. How to configure the value of ccsid used by **MQ Explorer**?
> 2. What kind of ccsid am i supposed to select for MQExplorer in order to communicate with remote QMGR? Besides this, where can i find the information about the ccsid compatibility?
> 3. From the MQ perspective, when communicating through client and server, what is the procedure to check CCSID compatibility? I know the MQ has data conversion table installed on OS, such as files under /usr/lib/nls/loc/iconvTable for AIX. Then how does the MQ make use of it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @T.Rob can u help answer it? Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

1. You can set your environment variable [MQCCSID](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaf.doc/cs12290_.htm).
2. The supported conversions depend on the platform the queue manager is running on, see [Code Page Conversions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzak.doc/fr20890_.htm) for a list of supported conversions.
3. as far as I know, it uses iconv on Unix, I don't know how it handles that on Windows exactly.